# When can a locally compact group be approximated by discrete subgroups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

This question is about partitioning a (locally) compact group into cells by using discrete subgroups.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.  (I am really most interested in the case where $G$ is a metrizable group.)  Say that $G$ is *“approximable by discrete subgroups”* if there is a sequence of countable/finite locally compact subgroups $G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq G_3 \subseteq ... \subseteq G$ such that for all $n$, $G/G_n$ is a compact group and $\bigcup_n G_n$ is dense in $G$.

This property clearly holds for $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$, addition on the torus, and products of finite groups.

- **Question 1:** Is there a characterization of locally compact groups “approximable by discrete subgroups”?  For example, is every metrizable locally compact group “approximable by discrete subgroups”?  Every Lie group?

My motivation is that such groups can be partitioned into cells based on these approximations.  This allows me to discretize the group and solve the problem I am currently working on.  (I also need to apply other methods to handle points which are close together but in different cells.)  I am basically trying to generalize a proof for addition on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to other locally compact metrizable groups.

- **Question 2:** (Vague!) If not all metrizable compact groups are “approximable by discrete subgroups,” is there any well-known techniques to nicely divide up a compact group into regions which are almost translates of each other, or something similar to the above idea.

---

*Disclaimer:* I apologize if this is not at the level of MO.  It is a research question, but I know very little about topological groups.  Also, I am happy to get pointed to useful resources on this subject.

Comment: Are you assuming in your definition that each $G_n$ is closed in $G$? Without this assumption, the quotient topology on $G/G_n$ won't be Hausdorff, I think

Comment: I fear that this property (strictly required) is difficult to achieve... My guess would be that, among real Lie groups, for example, only nilpotent groups would have this property. But this is just a superficial reaction...

Comment: Do you really need $G/G_n$ to be a group, or is it just compactness that you want?

Comment: A countable (= at most countable) locally compact group is discrete. So the weird "locally compact subgroup" just means discrete subgroup, and a discrete subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is compact is known as a "cocompact lattice" or "uniform lattice".

Comment: It is an old result of H. Toyama that if a connected Lie group is approximable by discrete subgroups, then it is nilpotent (and this even holds assuming only that the subgroups are discrete, not necessarily cocompact). By the way your definition should at least be called "approximable by discrete cocompact subgroups".

Comment: Second, the bare existence of a discrete cocompact subgroup is a quite strong property, which for instance implies that the group is unimodular.

Comment: So now that @YCor's scholarship has "grounded" the question... we can hopefully-usefully restrict the question to a regime where the outcome is positive for the immediate purposes? Clarification?

Comment: By Kuranishi (1951), a simply connected nilpotent Lie group is approximable by discrete subgroups iff it has a cocompact lattice, iff its Lie algebra has a rational structure. He also proved that a nilpotent Lie group has is approximable by discrete subgroup iff it has a cocompact lattice, iff its Lie algebra has a rational structure such that the kernel of the universal covering is a rational subgroup.

Comment: At the opposite I'm not sure the case of totally disconnected locally compact groups is so well understood.

Comment: Btw I should add the usual definition of approximable by discrete subgroups (for a 2nd countable locally compact group $G$): the existence of a sequence $(H_n)$ of discrete subgroups such that for every nonempty open subset $U$ of $G$ there exists $N=N_U$ such that $H_n\cap U\neq\emptyset$ for all $n\ge N$ (if $(H_n)$ is ascending this just means that the union is dense). The above characterizations anyway are correct with either definition.

Comment: I don't know if this helps for the application you have in mind, but for t.d.l.c. groups, an alternative way to approximate the group by discrete objects is to look instead at coset spaces $G/U$ where $U$ ranges over a base of identity neighbourhoods consisting of compact open subgroups.  If $G$ is a SIN group, then you can also make $U$ normal in $G$, so $G/U$ is a discrete quotient group of $G$ in the natural sense.